# How to write Pinyin using default keyboard languages?

Tags: keyboard, languages, samsung-galaxy-tab-2-10.1

I need to be able to make one of the tone marks in Pinyin, specifically the one that looks like a little U over the vowels. (example: ǎ )

I have tested various languages, but can't find one to add that allows me to do this accent on all vowels (a, e, i, o, u) on my Galaxy Tab 2 10.1. Is there a way to do this?